# Windows Phone 8.1 Push notification Testing App error : The Push Notification System is unavailable

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I am following one tutorial blog to learn Push Notification for Windows Phone 8.1

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2014/04/24/windows-phone-8-1-running-code-in-response-to-cloud-push-notifications.aspx

I am trying to test it from Azure Notification Service "Send Test Notification", there am getting below error:

[image]

The Push Notification System is unavailable

Any Input on this.

I have added a button also and on click i have written below code

```
private async void OnRegister(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
                NotificationHub hub = new NotificationHub("jaydeepapp", "ccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=hQm+Sq15ijRglWGacnngtzUu2wKL3MKcAz0X4xsmo1Y=");

                await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(channel.Uri, new string[] { "Hi", "Jaydeep" });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

code is executing without error but i am not getting the Push notification on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Azure is developing rapidly. Try this [manual](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-phone-get-started-push/) for add push notifications to your app. If there are problems try [Azure diagnosis guidelines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-diagnosing/)